# Dual Y axis line chart in d3.js without external data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 (and javascript and html), but please bear with me. My overall goal is to implement some d3 charts within FileMaker Pro (FMP - a relational database) and in particular its mobile counterpart FileMaker Go. This is because the charting options within FMP are limited. FMP does provide a web viewer that can render url's, or html and javascript code stored locally without needing an internet connection. I have replicated some examples provided on the d3 site, and wish to replicate this example but without having to resort to an external csv file:

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e34791a32a54e015f57d

I have replicated the above example in a browser using an external csv file, but not yet in FMP.

I have attempted to follow some other examples where the data is embedded within the d3 code, but without success. FMP allows me to to undertake calculations/text substitutions that will structure the data in the "correct" format and insert it within the d3 code, allowing the chart to update dynamically. This also applies to the d3 libraries. I have applied this successfully to:

http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6

Based on the d3noob example above, and reading on how "inline" data should be structured within the d3 code, I have come up with the following code, but it doesn't work. I have modified the code for the x axis to allow for continuous data rather than dates, and included my data rather than that of the original example.

Can someone advise me as to how the d3 code and data should be structured to function with "inline" data? Additionally, I would like to achieve a single vertical line for the "open" data series (y1 - second or right hand y axis) that identifies the maximum value for that data series. It would be a different colour and rise vertically from the appropriate x value (where y1 = 0) to the peak of the curve (y1=1300, x=25 in the data below).

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y0)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1)
    .orient("right").ticks(5); 

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y0(d.close); });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y1(d.open); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var data = [
{date: "0",close: "59.8",open: "897"},
{date: "1",close: "63.3",open: "943.5"},
{date: "2",close: "66.6",open: "988"},
{date: "3",close: "69.5",open: "1025.5"},
{date: "4",close: "72.2",open: "1061"},
{date: "5",close: "74.7",open: "1092.5"},
{date: "6",close: "76.9",open: "1119.5"},
{date: "7",close: "79",open: "1146"},
{date: "8",close: "80.8",open: "1167"},
{date: "9",close: "82.5",open: "1187.5"},
{date: "10",close: "84.1",open: "1205.5"},
{date: "11",close: "85.5",open: "1220.5"},
{date: "12",close: "86.8",open: "1235"},
{date: "13",close: "87.9",open: "1245.5"},
{date: "14",close: "89",open: "1257"},
{date: "15",close: "90",open: "1266"},
{date: "16",close: "90.9",open: "1273.5"},
{date: "17",close: "91.7",open: "1280.5"},
{date: "18",close: "92.4",open: "1285"},
{date: "19",close: "93.1",open: "1290.5"},
{date: "20",close: "93.7",open: "1293.5"},
{date: "21",close: "94.3",open: "1296.5"},
{date: "22",close: "94.8",open: "1299"},
{date: "23",close: "95.2",open: "1299"},
{date: "24",close: "95.6",open: "1299.5"},
{date: "25",close: "96",open: "1300"},
{date: "26",close: "96.4",open: "1299.6"},
{date: "27",close: "96.7",open: "1299.5"},
{date: "28",close: "97",open: "1298"},
{date: "29",close: "97.3",open: "1297.5"},
{date: "30",close: "97.5",open: "1294.5"},
{date: "31",close: "97.7",open: "1291.5"},
{date: "32",close: "97.9",open: "1289.5"},
{date: "33",close: "98.1",open: "1286.5"},
{date: "34",close: "98.3",open: "1284.5"},
{date: "35",close: "98.4",open: "1280"},
{date: "36",close: "98.6",open: "1277"},
{date: "37",close: "98.7",open: "1273.5"},
{date: "38",close: "98.8",open: "1269"},
{date: "39",close: "98.9",open: "1265.5"},
{date: "40",close: "99",open: "1261"},
{date: "41",close: "99.1",open: "1256.5"},
{date: "42",close: "99.2",open: "1253"},
{date: "43",close: "99.3",open: "1248.5"},
{date: "44",close: "99.3",open: "1243.5"},
{date: "45",close: "99.4",open: "1239"},
{date: "46",close: "99.4",open: "1233"},
{date: "47",close: "99.5",open: "1229.5"},
{date: "48",close: "99.5",open: "1223.5"},
{date: "49",close: "99.6",open: "1220"},
{date: "50",close: "99.6",open: "1214"},
{date: "51",close: "99.6",open: "1208"},
{date: "52",close: "99.7",open: "1204.5"},
{date: "53",close: "99.7",open: "1198.5"},
{date: "54",close: "99.7",open: "1193.5"},
{date: "55",close: "99.8",open: "1189"},
{date: "56",close: "99.8",open: "1183"},
{date: "57",close: "99.8",open: "1178"},
{date: "58",close: "99.8",open: "1172"},
{date: "59",close: "99.8",open: "1167"},
{date: "60",close: "99.8",open: "1161"},
{date: "61",close: "99.9",open: "1156.5"},
{date: "62",close: "99.9",open: "1151.5"},
{date: "63",close: "99.9",open: "1145.5"},
{date: "64",close: "99.9",open: "1140.5"},
{date: "65",close: "99.9",open: "1134.5"},
{date: "66",close: "99.9",open: "1128.5"},
{date: "67",close: "99.9",open: "1123.5"},
{date: "68",close: "99.9",open: "1117.5"},
{date: "69",close: "99.9",open: "1112.5"},
{date: "70",close: "99.9",open: "1106.5"},
{date: "71",close: "99.9",open: "1100.5"},
{date: "72",close: "99.9",open: "1095.5"},
{date: "73",close: "100",open: "1091"},
{date: "74",close: "100",open: "1086"},
{date: "75",close: "100",open: "1080"},
{date: "76",close: "100",open: "1074"},
{date: "77",close: "100",open: "1069"},
{date: "78",close: "100",open: "1063"},
{date: "79",close: "100",open: "1058"},
{date: "80",close: "100",open: "1052"},
{date: "81",close: "100",open: "1046"},
{date: "82",close: "100",open: "1041"},
{date: "83",close: "100",open: "1035"},
{date: "84",close: "100",open: "1030"},
{date: "85",close: "100",open: "1024"},
{date: "86",close: "100",open: "1018"},
{date: "87",close: "100",open: "1013"},
{date: "88",close: "100",open: "1007"},
{date: "89",close: "100",open: "1002"},
{date: "90",close: "100",open: "996"},
{date: "91",close: "100",open: "990"},
{date: "92",close: "100",open: "985"},
{date: "93",close: "100",open: "979"},
{date: "94",close: "100",open: "974"},
{date: "95",close: "100",open: "968"},
{date: "96",close: "100",open: "962"},
{date: "97",close: "100",open: "957"},
{date: "98",close: "100",open: "951"},
{date: "99",close: "100",open: "946"},
{date: "100",close: "100",open: "940"},
];

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y0.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return Math.max(d.close); })]); 
    y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
        return Math.max(d.open); })]);

    svg.append("path")        // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    svg.append("path")        // Add the valueline2 path.
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("d", valueline2(data));

    svg.append("g")            // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .call(yAxisLeft);   

    svg.append("g")             
        .attr("class", "y axis")    
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")   
        .style("fill", "red")       
        .call(yAxisRight);

});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your code working after adjusting one line:

http://jsfiddle.net/spanndemic/tyLvshfa/

There is an extra `});` at the end of the script, which is commented out in the above fiddle:

```
svg.append("g")             
    .attr("class", "y axis")    
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")   
    .style("fill", "red")       
    .call(yAxisRight);

//});
```

**Update:**

Example of how to draw a line at the max data value... you have to find the object in the array that has the maximum 'open' value, then draw a line based of the value.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spanndemic/tyLvshfa/

Additional Code:

```
// get the data object that has the max;
var openMax = 0;
var openMaxData;
data.forEach(function(el, i){
    if (parseInt(el.open) > openMax) {
        openMaxData = el;
        openMax = el.open;
    }
});

// append the line
svg.append("line")
    .attr("class", "maximum")
    .attr("x1", x(openMaxData.date))
    .attr("x2", x(openMaxData.date))
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", height);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much - that worked perfectly. Any further thoughts on how I would achieve a vertical line for the "open" data series (y1 - second or right hand y axis) that identifies the maximum value for that data series. It would be a different colour and rise vertically from the appropriate x value (where y1 = 0) to the peak of the curve (y1=1300, x=25 in the data provided)?

Comment: updated the answer/fiddle with an example of the line

Comment: Additional code worked fantastically thank you. I have also managed to follow some other code about adding axis titles to the x and y0 and y1 axes. Based on the variety of data I will have on the y1 axis, I will have to either adjust the range dynamically, or adjust the y1 domain lower value so that it can be negative. That shouldn't be too difficult either in d3, or inserting appropriate values via FMP calculation engine.

Comment: spandemic:This example is great... the difference I have between the Fiddle and my standalone version of this is that the top of the second Y axis shows values as 1,20 in mine, rather than 1,200. Any ideas where this rounding is coming from??     weaverd: as an FMP use too, any chance you could post the code to add the titles??